# Subclasses constructor in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, constructor, subclass

trying to build a programmable calculator in Ruby with classes, which can be extended with various operations. Logic: at first initialize calculator class with `Calculator.new`, then add the command as a subclass, like `Calculator.new.add_command (“+”, ClassName)`.

I’ve failed to figure out how to automate the creation of subclasses with the class method but reached the extension of functionality with Ruby’s builtin `public_send method`, so the code looks like that:

```
class Calculator 
attr_accessor :num1, :calc

def initialize(num1)
    @num1 = num1 
    @calc = []
end

def compute(operation, num)
    if @calc.length == 0
       @calc[0] = @num1.public_send(operation, num)
    else 
       @calc[0] = @calc[0].public_send(operation, num)
    end
end

def result
    @calc[0]
end
end
cal = Calculator.new(1)
cal.compute(:+, 1)
p cal.result => 2
```

Is there a way to build subclasses with class methods and pass them the functionality like `public_send`?

Also, the calculator is not a traditional one: at the initializing stage it should take one parameter, which is the first number, each next operation should take the second number and work with the previous operation's result. Like:

```
Calculator.new(1) 
cal.compute(“+”, 2) => 1 + 2 =  3 
cal.compute(“-”, 1) =>  3 - 1 = 2
cal.compute(“**”, 2) => 2 ** 2 = 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hash (`@commands`) that maps the operations to their respective class or module:

```
class Calculator
  attr_accessor :num1, :calc

  def initialize(num1)
    @num1 = num1
    @calc = []
    @commands = {}
  end

  def add_command(operation, callable)
    @commands[operation] = callable
  end

  # ...
end
```

You also need some convention for the method's name, let's pick `call`:

```
class Calculator
  # ...

  def compute(operation, num)
    if @calc.length == 0
      @calc[0] = @commands[operation].call(@num1, num)
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Now all you need is an object that responds to `call`, e.g. a module with a class method:

```
module Addition
  def self.call(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end
```

To add `Addition` as the `:+` operation:

```
cal = Calculator.new(2)
cal.add_command(:+, Addition)
cal.compute(:+, 3)
cal.result #=> 5
```

You can also add a proc / lambda because they also respond to [`call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Proc.html#call-method):

```
cal = Calculator.new(2)
cal.add_command :+, ->(a, b) { a + b }
cal.compute(:+, 3)
cal.result #=> 5
```